# Neverwinter Nights Enhanced Edition Ubuntu/Mint fatal error

Tags: ubuntu

I play Neverwinter Nights Enhanced Edition on my favorite player world called The World of Avlis. Avlis is a role playing world with nine persistent servers with loads of custom content that just recently updated to Enhanced Edition which is made by Beam Dog.

The problem I am having, is that whenever I try and log into just one of their servers, (Visimontium) trying with two different computers both running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and another running Mint 20.2 Cinnamon, the game crashes with a fatal error. I have posted the problem in their bug tracker and inquired on their discord channel; I guess I'm the only Linux user on Avlis. I have also had no issues on other player worlds with the two computers that I have tried on them.

Three different computers, two with Ubuntu one with Mint. I have only posted two examples here. I hope someone can decipher all that "lingedy"

Thank you anyone who can help me solve this issue

https://dev.avlis.org/issues/2692#change-23483

Comment: This isn't really on-topic here (because it's about a problem with third-party data files on a third-party server - nothing to do with unix or linux), **but** have you tried running the windows version of NwNEE with Proton instead of the linux native version? If so, does it have the same problem?   Try Proton, then try Proton Experimental.  And if neither of them work, maybe try a custom fork of proton like [Glorious Eggroll's fork](https://github.com/GloriousEggroll/proton-ge-custom/releases/).

Comment: And, yes, it's kind of wrong to run the windows version with proton rather than the native linux version, but sometimes that just works better.  In my experience it's not uncommon for linux native versions of games to be abandoned after they've been released, so in only a few years they crash because they depend on long-obsolete versions of common libraries. That doesn't seem to be the case for NwNEE (the windows .exe for NwNEE has the same date, 2021-12-13, as the linux version), but `nwmain-linux` depends on libraries (e.g. libc and libstdc++) that have been updated many times since last Dec

Comment: Thank you for the reply in spite of my posting error.  I don't think my issue is a Linux problem either.  I appreciate the Linux communities intelligence and helpfulness.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a problem of a third-party application on a third-party server (which the OP seems to agree with).